# How to get the picture when onFaceDetection called?

Tags: android, camera, face-detection

I' using onFaceDetection function.(at interface [FaceDetectionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html))
The function gets two parameter, FACE[] and Camera. 
How can I get the picture itself?

If I use Camera.PictureCallback.takePicture function, it looks like there is some interval between detection and taking a frame.

Comment: use Preview callback instead of picture callback

Comment: @yuva I tried. But how can I get 'the' frame on which faces are detected?

Comment: http://ibuzzlog.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-do-real-time-image-processing-in.html

Comment: check this you just have to get the frames convert it to bitmap and apply face recognition code to it

Comment: @yuva I tried. but it was too slow then using FaceDetectionListener. Anyway thank you for your comment and I will see the link narrowly.